# PHP api rest router issue

Tags: php, api, routes, retrofit

To test my android application in a more concrete way, and since my company has no API yet, I decided to "create" it in a simplified way for testing purpose (and learning, i'm only an intern).

The Android app uses Retrofit.

Anyway, I followed one tutorial for a "login" method, where I use the "Post" method in android, passing login and password as @field datas, and everything worked fine, I could retrieve the data in my android app and log in (I do not manage security yet, this will be added later when they hire a devOp)

The problem is after that I wanted to create a Router for more complicated urls (like "/model/client/:id/contracts") and now nothing work anymore. I do not use framework, only composer. I end my internship in two days I do not really have time to learn a big thing.

So, here are the classes that were working before I make the router :

/src/Model/client/login.php :

```
    <?php

namespace App\Model\client;

// required headers
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: access');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
header('Content-Type: application/json');

// include database and object files
include_once 'src/config/Database.php';
include_once 'src/Model/client/client.php';

// Instantiate database and connect
$database = new Database();
$db = $database->connect();

// prepare product object
$client = new Client($db);

console.log("Login launched");

// set ID property of record to read
$client->login = isset($_POST['login']) ? $_POST['login'] : die();
$client->password = isset($_POST['password']) ? $_POST['password'] : die();

// read the details of product to be edited
$result = $client->readOne();
$num = $result->rowCount();

//Check if corresponding client
if($num>0){

    if($client->city==3){
        $client->city = "Valenciennes";
    }

    $row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    if($row['city']==3){
        $city = "Valenciennes";
    } else {$city='randomname';}


 $client->id = $row['id'];
 $client->login = $row['login'];
 $client->raison = $row['raison'];
 $client->addr1 = $row['addr1'];
 $client->addr2 = $row['addr2'];
 $client->city = $city;
 $client->telephone = $row['telephone'];
 $client->portable = $row['portable'];
 $client->fax = $row['fax'];
 $client->email = $row['email'];
 $client->tva_intra = $row['tva_intra'];
 $client->siret = $row['siret'];
 $client->gtr = $row['gtr'];
 $client->password = $row['password'];

    // create array
    $logged_client = array(
    'id' =>  $client->id,
    'login'=> $client->login,
    'raison' => $client->raison,
    'addr1' => $client->addr1,
    'addr2' => $client->addr2,
    'city' => $client->city,
    'telephone'=>$client->telephone,
    'portable'=>$client->portable,
    'fax'=>$client->fax,
    'email'=>$client->email,
    'tva_intra'=>$client->tva_intra,
    'siret'=>$client->siret,
    'password'=>$client->password);

     // set response code - 200 OK
    http_response_code(200);

    // make it json format
    echo json_encode($logged_client);
}

else {
    // set response code - 404 Not found
    http_response_code(404);

    // tell the user product does not exist
    echo json_encode(array("message" => "Client does not exist.".$client->login));
}
?>
```

The class of the object I need to retrieve (src/Model/client/client):

```
 <?php

class Client{

//db stuff
private $cnx;
private $table_name='client';   

//client properties
public $id;
public $login;
public $nom;
public $raison;
public $addr1;
public $addr2;
public $city;
public $telephone;
public $portable;
public $fax;
public $email;
public $tva_intra;
public $siret;
public $gtr;
public $password;

//constructor
public function __construct($db){
    $this->cnx = $db;
}

//GetOne ###########################################################################
function readOne(){
$query = 'SELECT * FROM '.$this->table_name.' WHERE login = ? AND password = ?';

    // prepare query statement
$stmt = $this->cnx->prepare($query);

 // bind id of product to be updated
 $stmt->bindParam(1, $this->login);
 $stmt->bindParam(2, $this->password);

 // execute query
 $stmt->execute();

 // get retrieved row
 return $stmt;
}
}
?>
```

The database exists, here is the connection and it worked fine :

```
<?php

class Database {

//DB Params
private $host='localhost';
private $db_name='techcrea';
private $username = 'root';
private $pwd = '';
private $cnx;

//DB Connect
public function connect(){
    $this->cnx = null;

    try {
        $this->cnx = new PDO('mysql:host='.$this->host.';dbname='. $this->db_name, $this->username,$this->pwd);

        $this->cnx->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);


    }catch(PDOException $e){
        echo 'Connection Error:'.$e->getMessage();
    }

    return $this->cnx;
}

}
```

So here are the problems starting : this are the classes I added and now nothing works anymore, I get router exception errors (no matching routes) etc..., not only in my android app that returns an "onfailure" response, but also when i try the url in my navigator :

1 - Index :

```
<?php

require 'vendor/autoload.php';


$router= new App\Router\Router($_GET['url']);

$router->get('/', function(){
    echo "homepage";
});

$router->post('/Model/client/login', function(){  
      //require_once 'src/Model/client/login.php';
 });

$router->get('/Model/client/:id/contrats', function($id){
 echo "contrats";
});

$router->run();
```

2 - Router

```
<?php

namespace App\Router;

class Router {

    private $url;
    private $routes =[];
    private $namedRoutes= [];

    public function __construct($url){


        $this->url = $url;
    }


public function get($path, $callable, $name =null){
    return $this->add($path,$callable,$name,'GET');
}

public function post($path, $callable, $name=null){
    return $this->add($path,$callable,$name,'POST');
}


public function patch($path, $callable, $name=null){
    return $this->add($path,$callable,$name,'PATCH');
}

public function put($path, $callable, $name=null){
    return $this->add($path,$callable,$name,'PUT');
}

public function delete($path, $callable, $name=null){
    return $this->add($path,$callable,$name,'DELETE');
}


private function add($path, $callable,$name,$method){
    $route = new Route($path, $callable);
    $this->routes[$method][]= $route;
    if($name){
        $this->namedRoutes[$name] = $route;
    }
    return $route;
}

public function url($name,$params = []){

    if(!isset($this->namedRoutes[$name])){
        throw new RouterException("no match name route");
    }
    $this->namedRoutes[$name]->getUrl($params);
}


public function run(){
    if(!isset($this->routes[$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']])){
        throw new RouterException('request method does not exist');
    }
    foreach($this->routes[$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']] as $route){

        if($route->match($this->url)){
           return $route->call();
        }
    }
    throw new RouterException('no matching routes');
}
}
```

3 - Route

namespace App\Router;

class Route {

```
private $path;
private $callable;
private $matches = [];
private $params = [];

public function __construct($path, $callable){
    $this->path = trim($path,'/');
    $this->callable = $callable;
}

public function with($param, $regex){
    $this->params[$param] = str_replace('(','(?:', $regex);
    return $this;
```

}

```
public function match($url){

    $url=trim($url, '/');
    $path = preg_replace_callback('#:([\w]+)#', [$this, 'paramMatch'], $this->path);
    $regex = "#^$path$#i";

    if(!preg_match($regex, $url, $matches)){
        return false;
    }

    array_shift($matches);
    $this->matches= $matches;
    return true;
}

public function call(){
    if(is_string($this->callable)){
        $params = explode('#', $this->callable);
        $controller = "App\\Controller\\".$params[0]."Controller";
        $controller = new $controller();
        $action = $params[1];
        return $controller->$action();

    } else {
    return call_user_func_array($this->callable, $this->matches);
}}


private function paramMatch($match){
    if(isset($this->params[$match[1]])){
        return '('.$this->params[$match[1]].')';
    }
    return '([^/]+)';
}

public function getUrl($params){
    $path = $this->path;
    foreach($params as $k=>$v){
    $path= str_replace(":$k",$v, $path);
    }
    return $path;
}
```

}

and the htaccess doc :

```
 RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Thank you very much if you help me

Comment: `now nothing work anymore` does not really provide much of a clue as to what does or does not happen and which files are at fault. Can you clarify this because there is a lot of code above that you might understand but everyone else has to try to figure out

Comment: in the question you reference `/model/client/:id/contracts` but in the index file `$router->get('/Model/client/:id/contrats'` ~ different spelling

Comment: Yes the contracts route does not exist yet, but it is "contrats" (french database, i kept the names) the mistake was in my question. To answer yours when I say "nothing works anymore" it is for the login url, before the router i got json response and could load the client data in my android app. Now I got an  exception "no matching routes". I tried alot of different urls but I don't understand what is wrong. The homepage url works and it displays "homepage" on the root url. The complete access is c:// htdocs/api/src/Model/client/login.php and the "api" is the root folder.

Comment: I deleted the "contrats" url to only leave the two other and the login one still does not work. (ps: sorry for my bad english i'm french I try my best)